# Searching through array object using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have some object inside Array that contains a recipe which i stored into localstorage, i tried to find a spesific recipe depends on my textbox.

Before that i tried to use static string as you can see i inputed "Pizza" , and it worked!

[image]

Here is the proof that it worked even though i inputed "a" on my textbox (searchTerm)
[image]

But when i tried to find it using my string from my textbox (searchTerm) it says undefined.

[image]

[image]

How is this happening ?

Comment: Sorry, i thought at first this was not a really big problem and still can be understood by looking at the pictures i gave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`search` is the object in your result, so you should compare with `search.searchTerm`.

```
receipes.find(recipes => recipe.name === searchsearchTerm)
```